# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS x AS (SELECT ...) inserts double records when executed twice?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I try to create a table as a select result of query as the following:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS x AS (SELECT ...)

That works fine and a new table x is created with adequate columns and content.
But when I re-execute the ddl query the existing table is populated again with the same content (so double...)

- After first execution, table x:

  ```
  1 a
  2 b
  3 c
  ```
- After secondexecution, table x:

  ```
  1 a
  2 b
  3 c
  1 a
  2 b
  3 c
  ```

Why? And how to resolva that? because this executed by a user in my app so it can be executed many times and that's why I put IF NOT EXISTS to not re create the table each time...

Best Regards,

Comment: create a sqlfiddle fo it

Answer (score 2):

This is version dependent.  As described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html):

> For `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`, if `IF NOT EXISTS` is given and the
>   destination table already exists, the result is version dependent.
>   Before MySQL 5.5.6, MySQL handles the statement as follows:
>
> - The table definition given in the `CREATE TABLE` part is ignored. No error occurs, even if the definition does not match that of the
>     existing table. MySQL attempts to insert the rows from the SELECT part
>     anyway.

Comment: As regards "*how to resolve that?*"—define a PK in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, before the `AS SELECT ...`, then duplicates will obviously be rejected.

Answer (score -1):

> MySQL applies these rules when various CREATE ... IF NOT EXISTS statements are replicated:
>
> Every CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS statement is replicated, whether
>   or not the database already exists on the master.
>
> Similarly, every CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statement without a SELECT
>   is replicated, whether or not the table already exists on the master.
>   This includes CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... LIKE. Replication of
>   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... SELECT follows somewhat different
>   rules; see Section 17.4.1.6, “Replication of CREATE TABLE ... SELECT
>   Statements”, for more information.
>
> For more information-  [CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS is always replicated in MySQL 5.5, whether
>   or not the event named in the statement already exists on the master.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-create-if-not-exists.html)

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with **replication**, which is a process by which multiple MySQL servers can be kept in sync.  This answer is totally irrelevant to the problem at hand, and of absolutely no use whatsoever to the OP.  That you posted it, and think it does not deserve to be downvoted, demonstrates an appalling lack of understanding of both the question and your own answer.  I'd downvote a second time if I could.

Comment: "appalling lack of understanding"- just the comment needed to encourage newbies on the platform to attempt questions and  try to answer better ! Thanks !

Comment: @RadAI: With respect, StackOverflow isn't supposed to be a site for newbies to guess at answers in the hope of getting it right.  It's supposed to be a site where people who *know* the answer share their knowledge.